# Unescape URL Unicode for display in go template

Tags: go, url, unicode

When a URL has unicode characters, web browsers helpfully display the URL in the true unicode form rather than the long string of %12%33, etc...

In Golang, when we output a variable using the builtin go `template.HTML`, the variable is escaped to be safe for HTML. But I want to go further and unescape the characters that were encoded with a % as well. What is the correct way to do this in Go?

To be clear, here is a screenshot, we just don't want URL's to appear ugly in our support/ticket system:

[image: Feedback form]

According to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_URL_EscapedPath) there is an `EscapedPath()` function, to work on the path only. But it would be ideal if was a means to apply Unicode transformation over the whole URL, including the domain name and query parameters. Does this exist already?

Comment: Would [html/template.URL](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#URL) be useful?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, good observation. My reading of the documentation suggests that the purpose of the template.URL type is to prevent any escaping occurring. But I will double check how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you say it needs to be the whole URL, these both seem to work
fine:

```
package main
import "net/url"

const (
   s = "https://biblicaltext.com/dictionary/%e1%bd%95%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%bf%cf%82?b=%cf%85"
   t = "https://biblicaltext.com/dictionary/ὕαλος?b=υ"
)

func main() {
   { // example 1
      u, e := url.PathUnescape(s)
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      println(u == t)
   }
   { // example 2
      u, e := url.QueryUnescape(s)
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      println(u == t)
   }
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#PathUnescape
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#QueryUnescape

Comment: Unicode can be embedded in the domain name as well.  (Web browsers typically auto decode Unicode in domain names and also paths.  But yes that solution works for the path!

Comment: Yea don’t you hate those people that don’t go back and tick the answer.   I’ve not had time to look at this part of the code yet. I’ll probably do it today